# How can I float divs so that they expand past their container?

Tags: html, css, css-float

```
<div class="story-container">
  <div class="story-box">
    <h3>News Item #2</h3>
    <h2>This is my second news item!!</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="story-box">
    <h3>Technical Development</h3>
    <h2>See Muppets on Your Band-Aid With New AR App</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

My CSS is:

```
.story-container {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 blue;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 1000px;
}

.story-box {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

I want the `story-box`'s to be next to each outer, but currently they don't do that. How can I make that happen?

**EDIT**

I want `story-box` to be 1000px as should the container. That way, the `story-box` takes up the full width of the container and then the next one is technically outside the bounds.

Comment: They look next to each other to me: http://jsfiddle.net/39uR8/

Comment: Edited my question to reflect my true desire

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of relying on `float`/`clear` to expand past the bounds of `story-container` you can instead add a new class `story-row` and set it's width to be very large.

```
<div class="story-container">
  <div class="story-row">            
      <div class="story-box">
        <h3>News Item #2</h3>
        <h2>This is my second news item!!</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="story-box">
        <h3>Technical Development</h3>
        <h2>See Muppets on Your Band-Aid With New AR App</h2>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
​

.story-container {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 blue;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.story-row {
  width: 2000px; /* num of stories by 1000px */
  position: absolute;
}

.story-box {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
    position: relative;
    width: 1000px;
    height:100px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/39uR8/17/

Now if you want to scroll the next story into view with javascript or something all you'll need to do it adjust the position of `story-row` by -1000px each time.

Comment: Edited my question to be more accurate

Answer (score 1):

Give a `width` to your `.story-box`

Edit : try `width: 490px;` if you want half width

[image]

Or `width: 990px;` to have this :
[image]